# What is the most rampant duplicate on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, fun

**Strongly related**: [How do we deal with octuplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9050/how-do-we-deal-with-octuplicate-questions)

This is not a question about how to deal with duplicates, it's a simple "meta" question:

What is the most rampant duplicate on Stack Overflow?

- The particular duplicate must be "alive" on Stack Overflow (not merged or closed duplicate)
- The duplicate-ness must be pretty unquestionable.

For example:

This is a duplicate of score <s>2</s> 1.

- <s>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227662/what-is-the-best-editor-or-ide-for-ruby-development</s> merged ;-p
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968/best-editor-for-ruby

They are both so close that it makes little sense to have separate questions.

However, score 2 is pretty uninteresting.

(The rationale of this question is to find the duplicates so we can get the administrators to merge them. It is also to find better ways to find dupes in the first place, and perhaps turn finding duplicates into a game.)

Comment: How is the "score" of a duplicate determined? The total number of duplicates?

Comment: Yerp, total number of "live" duplicates

Comment: With true irony, is this a duplicate? [How do we deal with octuplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9050/how-do-we-deal-with-octuplicate-questions)

Comment: Marc, this is about the search for the most rampant duplicate, which is one possible solution to the duplicate problem. its not about solving the problem, it a much narrower, and hopefully more fun question.

Comment: One that comes up again and again is floating point comparisons e.g. "why is `if (myFloat == 23)` not working?"

Comment: @mmyers is correct, this question is itself a dupe: [What's the most repeated question on StackOverflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26621/whats-the-most-repeated-question-on-stackoverflow)

Comment: @Josh: No, this question came months before the other.

Comment: @mmyers: Oh, you're right. Sorry! :-)

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46183/time-for-a-spring-cleaning-in-the-dusty-corner-of-net-mail-reading) for another 5 candidates + 2 more in the answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Regular Expression Help" gets asked most often, but we always change its title to something a bit more descriptive.

Comment: Fantastic question -- at last a rep-incentive for closing dupes, and **look ma no code changes**!  (Even if it's only meta-rep.)  IMHO it should be a requirement to list all the question URLs in your answer to get upvotes here.

Comment: Ironic that I also posted a duplicate: [Are duplicates creating broken windows?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52530/are-duplicates-creating-broken-windows)

Comment: [Question title that doesn't describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/203198?lq=1

Comment: What is the most rampant duplicate on Stack *Overflow*. Now do the actual title, please. (cross-site)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

How do you sketch Web Interfaces fast?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112803/what-is-the-best-web-prototyping-tool
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952558/what-kinds-of-tools-do-you-use-for-conceptual-design-of-your-software
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156755/tools-for-creating-ui-prototype
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408202/what-collaborative-wireframing-ui-mockup-tools-are-out-there
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250423/how-do-you-sketch-guis-web-interfaces-fast
- [Good diagramming software for UML and Webdesign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102110/good-diagramming-software-for-uml-and-webdesign)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563023/anyone-can-recommend-a-tool-to-mockup-web-pages
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295589/what-program-should-i-use-to-mock-up-guis
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528769/best-web-app-for-creating-screen-mockups
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54606/what-free-software-can-i-use-to-create-ui-mockups
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363/best-tools-for-creating-website-wireframes
- etc, etc, etc

Comment: which one of these has the best answer?

Comment: merge and have n users [where n=(number of questions)+(number of answers)] complain on meta about abusive behavior.

Comment: Not merely duplicates, but off topic.

Answer (score 91):

**How to parse HTML with RegEx?**

...by far has the most dupes.

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)
- [How to use regular expressions to parse HTML in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java)
- [regex for html parsing (in c#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271741/regex-for-html-parsing-in-c)
- [How to write a regular expression for html parsing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792679/need-help-writing-regular-expression-html-parsing)
- [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)
- [Regular Expression (regex) to Parse HTML Segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4728410/regular-expression-regex-to-parse-html-segment)

... just to name a few.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26621/whats-the-most-repeated-question-on-stackoverflow/26638#26638

Comment: Amazing that this continues to be asked despite [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1021259) classic answer.

Comment: @Rob Rose: That is the answer to #1 in the list (*"RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags"*).

Answer (score 84):

I *guess* it is:

**Me no can get program working - you help please code here pls debug. Thxxxx**

Comment: URRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRGNNNNNNNNNTTTTTTTTTTTTT PLLLLLLZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ

Comment: Apparently he/she has an assignment with a deadline :)

Comment: Four years later, this answer is still a  H O O T

Comment: @HowardPautz Six years later, it's *still* funny.

Comment: Don't forget "tanks in advantage"

Comment: @JAL: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/)

Answer (score 51):

On Server Fault, it's definitely "How do I host my server from home":

- https://serverfault.com/questions/66947/how-to-host-website-from-my-home-adsl
- [What are some pitfalls of hosting a website from home?](https://serverfault.com/questions/4658/what-are-some-pitfalls-of-hosting-a-website-from-home)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/127478/hosting-multiple-websites-from-home
- [Is it Possible to view my apache server (local host) from home or remote computer that is outside my LAN?](https://serverfault.com/questions/111614/is-it-possible-to-view-my-apache-server-local-host-from-home-or-remote-computer)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/27547/problem-hosting-server-behing-personal-router
- [Website hosting from home - IIS6](https://serverfault.com/questions/108232/website-hosting-from-home-iis6)
- [Server Hosting from your House - $200 to $300 per month range](https://serverfault.com/questions/36457/server-hosting-from-your-house-200-to-300-per-month-range)
- [Hosting a server for websites, ftp and random use at home?](https://serverfault.com/questions/128757/hosting-a-server-for-websites-ftp-and-random-use-at-home)
- [Can I have web server on a home network with 1 public IP address?](https://serverfault.com/questions/116643/can-i-have-web-server-on-a-home-network-with-1-public-ip-address)
- [Opinions on hosting servers in-house](https://serverfault.com/questions/70532/opinions-on-hosting-servers-in-house)
- [How necessary is a static IP when running a webserver from home](https://serverfault.com/questions/157346/how-necessary-is-a-static-ip-when-running-a-webserver-from-home)
- [How hard is it to host from home?](https://serverfault.com/questions/63515/how-hard-is-it-to-host-from-home)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/93846/setting-up-a-home-web-server
- [Set up Home computer as a Server to Access it at Uni](https://serverfault.com/questions/58262/set-up-home-computer-as-a-server-to-access-it-at-uni)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/107893/web-hosting-from-home-server
- [Set up server at home for running svn and Bugzilla](https://serverfault.com/questions/117477/set-up-server-at-home-for-running-svn-and-bugzilla)
- [Port forwarding my home server problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/180289/port-forwarding-my-home-server-problem)
- [How do I set up a web server out of my home?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1058/how-do-i-set-up-a-web-server-out-of-my-home)
- [Hosting a server for websites, ftp and random use at home?](https://serverfault.com/questions/128757/hosting-a-server-for-websites-ftp-and-random-use-at-home)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/368958/host-server-from-home-with-a-cloud-cdn-provider-or-go-with-cloud-server
- [Is this a secure setup for a home-based server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/61680/is-this-a-secure-setup-for-a-home-based-server)
- [How to setup VPN on home network](https://serverfault.com/questions/21251/how-to-setup-vpn-on-home-network)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/434337/building-a-server-at-home
- [Points to consider while building a home server](https://serverfault.com/questions/38287/points-to-consider-while-building-a-home-server)
- [Setup localhost on home computer as remote server](https://serverfault.com/questions/194956/setup-localhost-on-home-computer-as-remote-server)
- [For very beginning startup: home server or EC2?](https://serverfault.com/questions/431699/for-very-beginning-startup-home-server-or-ec2)
- [Assigning a home DNS to be secondary only?](https://serverfault.com/questions/128278/assigning-a-home-dns-to-be-secondary-only)
- [Home server security: where do I start?](https://serverfault.com/questions/22767/home-server-security-where-do-i-start)
- [Email hosting on home's Windows server 2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/141804/email-hosting-on-homes-windows-server-2003)
- [hosting a site using apache at home](https://serverfault.com/questions/251515/hosting-a-site-using-apache-at-home)
- [Website hosted at home pingable from outside, but not browseable from outside](https://serverfault.com/questions/229802/website-hosted-at-home-pingable-from-outside-but-not-browseable-from-outside)
- [Can I manually configure a domain name for Windows Home Server 2011 Remote Access?](https://serverfault.com/questions/277818/can-i-manually-configure-a-domain-name-for-windows-home-server-2011-remote-acces)
- [Cost effective way to host site / VPS / yourself?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215222/cost-effective-way-to-host-site-vps-yourself)
- [Does it make sense to self-host?](https://serverfault.com/questions/280340/does-it-make-sense-to-self-host)
- [Webserver at home: will my DSL line be good enough?](https://serverfault.com/questions/330788/webserver-at-home-will-my-dsl-line-be-good-enough)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/434983/setting-up-a-home-web-server-how-to-map-my-domain

(And that's not even all of them.)

Which is ridiculous because the answer is always "Don't" - and I thought this was a site meant for professionals...

Comment: Well, sometimes "don't" is the proper and professional answer... but that's a different discussion for a different time. I would have figured that was a prime target for duplicates, I just never expected that much ... variety ... in the wording.

Comment: Don't is definitely not the answer, the answer comes in regards to availability guidelines. If you only LIKE to have your site up, be all means host from home. If you NEED your site up. Use a real host.

Comment: What's scary is the same answer applies to "How to parse HTML with RegEx" - again the ideal answer is "Don't" but there are some limited cases where it's possible ;)

Comment: As of today, a search for +host +server +home turns up 1,153 results on SF. Not all of them are this question, but it appears that the vast majority are.

Comment: That looks more like a topic than a question archetype.

Answer (score 42):

[Since Jarrod spent so much time and effort cleansing the data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166646/note-which-post-a-question-was-closed-as-a-duplicate-of-in-the-revision-history/167985#167985), I figured it'd be a shame not to have some fun with it.

### Here are the top 30 questions (by # of questions closed as duplicates of them) on SO:

**9363**               [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384)
**4533**               [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)
**4070**               [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142)
**3304**               ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133)
**2974**               [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832)
**2937**               [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18050071)
**2271**               [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816)
**2240**               [mysql_fetch_array()/mysql_fetch_assoc()/mysql_fetch_row()/mysql_num_rows etc... expects parameter 1 to be resource](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2973202)
**1884**               [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982)
**1850**               [PHP mail function doesn't complete sending of e-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24644436)
**1745**               [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004)
**1642**               [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957)
**1398**               [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/203198)
**1391**               [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486)
**1325**               [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)
**1259**               [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11321491)
 **968**          [Why are these constructs using pre and post-increment undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/949433)
 **906**          [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/495021)
 **859**          [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5554734)
 **855**          [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170)
 **842**          [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)
 **810**          [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484)
 **794**          [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086)
 **754**          [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618)
 **745**          [Can I mix MySQL APIs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17498216)
 **724**          [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40480)
 **703**          [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045)
 **685**          [How can I fix 'android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166)
 **636**          [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13840429)
 **628**          [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125)

<sub>(And yes, I'm counting deleted posts too - lookin' at you, PHP)</sub>

---

```
select top 30 count(*) as dups, 
  concat('site://q/', RelatedPostId, '|', isnull(q.Title, RelatedPostId)) as Q,
 iif(max(q.ClosedDate) is not null, '*', '') as Closed,
 iif(max(q.DeletionDate) is not null, '*', '') as Deleted

from PostLinks
 join PostsWithDeleted q on q.Id=RelatedPostId

where LinkTypeId=3

group by RelatedPostId, q.Title
order by count(*) desc
```

This is now available for your use and abuse on [the Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/162750/most-duplicated-questions?opt.textResults=true)!

Comment: The MySQL one would have been my guess for the top-spot... they're a never-ending deluge; and those are just the ones that got closed as dupes of the merged dupes at the top... your query isn't recursive ;-).

Comment: The data code appears to be broken. I have posted a new version on my answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/244636/200117

Comment: I wonder why the top questions among these all involve PHP… :]

Comment: These days, the top one is [java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/218384), @balu - never a dull moment!

Comment: Using that query, unsurprisingly, the top one on meta SO and meta SE is "What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?" (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Answer (score 22):

The worst offender in my books is "How do I run multiple versions of IE on the same machine?"

Dupes of [Running Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Internet Explorer 8 on the same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574463/running-internet-explorer-6-internet-explorer-7-and-internet-explorer-8-on-the):

- [Multiple Internet Explorer version browser testing (Internet Explorer 6-8)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465343/multiple-ie-version-browser-testing-ie-6-8)
- [Internet Explorer 8 and Internet Explorer 6 side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135057/internet-explorer-8-and-ie-6-side-by-side)
- [Multiple Internet Explorer instances on one machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693112/multiple-ie-instances-on-one-machine)
- [Multiple Internet Explorer browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030466/multiple-ie-browsers-closed)
- [Testing the website accross multiple IE versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3782541/testing-the-website-accross-multiple-ie-versions-closed)
- [Internet Explorer 6 and Internet Explorer 7 on same computer for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669124/ie-6-and-ie-7-on-same-computer-for-debugging)
- [How to debug with an older version of Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407487/how-to-debug-with-an-older-version-of-ie)
- [How to run all three versions of Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342927/how-to-run-all-three-versions-of-ie)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484/how-do-you-test-layout-design-across-multiple-browsers-oss
- [Internet Explorer 6 testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682559/internet-explorer-6-testing)
- [Is it possible to degrade from Internet Explorer 7 to Internet Explorer 6 for debugging purposes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421945/is-it-possible-to-degrade-from-ie7-to-ie6-for-debugging-purposes)
- [What's the best way to test cross-browser compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298147/whats-the-best-way-to-test-cross-browser-compatibility)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796229/ie-browser-testing-for-windows-7
- [Internet Explorer 6 emulator recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300057/ie6-emulator-recommendation)
- [Run multiple versions of Internet Explorer on Windows Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310887/run-multiple-versions-of-internet-explorer-on-windows-vista)
- [Need a good Internet Explorer 6, 7, 8 standalone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065989/need-a-good-internet-explorer-6-7-8-standalone)
- [How can I view more than one version of IE on my computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223120/how-can-i-view-more-than-one-version-of-ie-on-my-computer)
- [how to install multiple versions of IE on the same system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909459/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-ie-at-the-same-time)

It goes on and on and it depresses me to no end.

Answer (score 14):

One I see often is "How do I center an element vertically and horizontally with CSS?"

Comment: The worst part is this question has like 8500 answers all of which work in some ways and don't work in others.

Answer (score 12):

Attempting to modify a C string results in an access violation:

- [Modifying a C string: access violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1025927/modifying-a-c-string-access-violation-closed)
- [Why does simple C code receive segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-does-simple-c-code-receive-segmentation-fault)
- [Modifying C string constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480555/modifying-c-string-constants)
- [Cannot modify C string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455970/cannot-modify-c-string)

This must come up once a week.

Answer (score 12):

**Should I learn [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)?**

[Will Emacs make me a better programmer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485120/will-emacs-make-me-a-better-programmer)
[Is it worth investing time in learning to use Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48006/is-it-worth-investing-time-in-learning-to-use-emacs)
<strike>[Should I learn to use Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551289/should-i-learn-to-use-emacs-closed)</strike>
[Are there any reasons why a C# developer should learn Emacs/Vim?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646438/any-reasons-why-a-c-developer-should-learn-emacs)
[Would you recommend vim/emacs for beginner programmers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208256/would-you-recommend-emacs-for-beginners)
[Is it worth learning to use Emacs for web development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384629/is-it-worth-learning-to-use-emacs-for-web-development)

**How to learn Emacs?**

[How do you learn proper Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502399/how-do-you-learn-proper-emacs)
[How to quickly get started at using and learning Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269812/how-to-quickly-get-started-at-using-and-learning-emacs)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210791/good-resources-for-emacs
[Resources for learning Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896648/resources-for-learning-emacs)
[Forcing myself to master Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978238/forcing-myself-to-master-emacs)

**Emacs/Vim vs IDEs** is popular, though not really exact duplicates per se, they are all editor vs different IDE questions.

[What specific productivity gains do Vim/Emacs provide over GUI text editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088387/specific-productivity-gains-vim-emacs-over-gui-editors)
[From Visual Studio to Vim or Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786887/from-visual-studio-to-vim-or-emacs-closed) (closed subjective, not dupe)
[Why Emacs/Vim/Textmate? Isn't Xcode good enough?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649000/why-emacs-vim-textmate-isnt-xcode-good-enough)
[Why should I use an IDE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208193/why-should-i-use-an-ide)
[What are the efficiencies afforded by Emacs or Vim vs Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346820/efficiencies-afforded-by-emacs-or-vim-vs-eclipse)
[C++ development on linux Code::Blocks, EMACS or GVIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/672770/c-development-on-linux-codeblocks-emacs-or-gvim)
[Which editors out of Emacs, Vim and JEdit support multiple simultaneous text insertion points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396495/emacs-and-vim-vs-jedit)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136056/ide-or-text-editor
[Emacs in the era of IDEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004682/emacs-in-the-era-of-ides)
[What modern editors compete with emacs/vi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714279/what-modern-editors-compete-with-emacs-vi)
[Java programming environment : emacs or eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402636/java-programming-environment-emacs-or-eclipse)
[Eclipse, is there a reason to chose it over emacs or vi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464139/eclipse-is-there-a-reason-to-chose-it-over-emacs-or-vi)

Answer (score 10):

"Best HTML parser in Java" or equivalent:

- [HTML/XML Parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129375/html-xml-parser-for-java)
- [Which HTML Parser is the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best)
- [Any good Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806131/any-good-java-html-parsers)
- [recommendations for a java HTML parser/editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709233/recommendations-for-a-java-html-parser-editor)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386846/can-anyone-suggest-a-good-open-source-html-parser-to-be-used-with-java
- [Java HTML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing)
- [How to "scan" a website (or page) for info, and bring it into my program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835505/how-to-scan-a-website-or-page-for-info-and-bring-it-into-my-program)
- [Text Extraction from HTML Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386107/text-extraction-from-html-java)
- [How can I parse a HTML string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497946/how-can-i-parse-a-html-string-in-java)
- etc, etc, etc

Answer (score 6):

I have a 3 pointer:

[Any decent C# profilers out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644/any-decent-c-profilers-out-there/231577)
[Best .NET memory and performance profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912/best-dotnet-memory-and-performance-profiler)
[What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Really they should all be folded into a single mega community wiki .... There is no value in having the 3 questions.

Comment: Agreed, they should probably be merged. **3** points for you :)

Answer (score 5):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=learn+programming

That's a duplicate score too high to count.

Comment: Eric, there is no clear unambiguous list for the moderator to work with. See how Marc was able to resolve the dupe I posted in seconds. Surely you could beat my measly score of 2.

Answer (score 4):

["foreach captured variable c#"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%2Bforeach+%2Bcaptured+%2Bvariable+%2Bc%23+site:stackoverflow.com)

Jon kindly listed some of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295593#295597)... and that was just in November; it will be longer now...

The problem with this language gotcha is that until you understand what is happening, you can't know what to look for... IMO, this is one of the good use-cases for tag-specific home pages, where we can (manually) add a FAQ for that tag (i.e. link to the canonical answer).

Answer (score 4):

Ampersand language operators. Actually might be worthwhile improving search so that it can look for ampersands.

For Ruby that would be "What's the meaning of `&:name`":

- [Understanding [ClassOne, ClassTwo].each(&:my_method)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99318/understanding-classone-classtwo-eachmy-method)
- [What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)
- [What exactly is `&:capitalize` in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792683/what-exactly-is-is-this-in-ruby-capitalize)
- [Ruby ampersand colon shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961030/ruby-ruby-on-rails-ampersand-colon-shortcut)
- [Ruby : `&:symbol` syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096975/ruby-symbol-syntax)
- [What is this &:last Ruby construct called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211751/what-is-this-last-ruby-construct-called)
- [What do you call the &: operator in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259775/what-do-you-call-the-operator-in-ruby)
- [What does map(&:name) do in this Ruby code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388337/what-does-mapname-do-in-this-ruby-code)
- [What are :+ and &:+ in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697024/what-are-and-in-ruby)
- [`&:views_count` in `Post.published.collect(&:views_count)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888044/views-count-in-post-published-collectviews-count)
- [Ruby Proc Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4512587/ruby-proc-syntax)
- [How does "(1..4).inject(&:+)" work in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003257/how-does-1-4-inject-work-in-ruby)

PHP: What does the `&` or `=&` operator mean?

- [What do the "=&" and "&=" operators in PHP mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367454/what-do-operators-in-php-mean)
- [PHP assignment operator =&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200009/php-assigment-operator)
- [Reference assignment operator in PHP, =&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768343/reference-assignment-operator-in-php)
- [=& operator in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864510/operator-in-php)
- [Reference assignment operator in PHP, =&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1768343/reference-assignment-operator-in-php)
- [php using '&' operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721986/php-using-operator)
- [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
- [How does the "&" operator work in a PHP function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957584/how-does-operator-work-in-php-function)
- [What does the PHP operator =& mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526555/what-does-this-php-operator-means)
- [Understanding PHP & (ampersand, bitwise and) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600202/understanding-phps-operator)

Answer (score 4):

**Data query tested in 2016**

Shog9's Data Explorer query didn't seem to work for me, so I crafted one that did: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/254033/rampant-duplicates-questions-with-the-most-duplicates

```
SELECT TOP 100
  l.RelatedPostId AS [Post Link],
  COUNT(l.PostId) AS DupCount
FROM
  PostLinks l
WHERE
  l.LinkTypeId = 3
GROUP BY
  l.RelatedPostId
ORDER BY
  DupCount DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

This is quite "rampant": [Best Java 7 features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082555/best-java-7-features)

Pretty much exact duplicate of [What new features in java 7 do you find most useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214289/what-new-features-in-java-7-do-you-find-most-useful) (posted 9 months earlier), very close to [What are you looking forward to in Java 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460938/what-are-you-looking-forward-to-in-java-7) (6 months earlier), and somewhat close to [many others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java7).

What also springs to mind are the *countless* variations on the theme "What is the best Python (web) framework?", with ever so subtle differences in emphasis and formulation. (Right now I'm not delving too deep into those, but take a look at [python+frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+frameworks),  [python+framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+framework) and [python+web-frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-frameworks+python).)

Comment: +1, you get a score of **2** for this, I'm only giving points for exact dupes that can be merged, and are listed here :p

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213958/new-features-in-java-7

Comment: Look at these two answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460938/-/460955#460955 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082555/-/1082581#1082581

Answer (score 3):

Android has some serious flaws in its touch event model, and this has caused many people to ask how to fix the problem (the real answer seems to be "upgrade to Gingerbread", sadly):

- [Why are touch events destroying my Android framerate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792185/why-are-touch-events-destroying-my-android-framerate)
- [Android: Touch seriously slowing my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342464/android-touch-seriously-slowing-my-application)
- [2D game on Android SurfaceView runs slowly on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597250/2d-game-on-android-surfaceview-runs-slowly-on-touch)
- [Excessive number of touch events slows down Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345471/excessive-number-of-touch-events-slows-down-android-app)

I've marked most of these of dupes of the original, not sure if merging or what is the solution here. The bug report mentioned in [4342464](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342464/android-touch-seriously-slowing-my-application/4348388#4348388) is the most correct answer IME.

Answer (score 2):

In the past:

> [Why/When] Should I use xxxx
>   Programming Language?

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate row values into a single column is fairly common for SQL Server

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Concatenate+row+%5BSQL-Server%5D

Comment: Can you create a list of actual merge candidates, so I can score it :p

Answer (score 1):

I feel like mod_rewrite should be on this list but I'm too lazy to go look up a lot of duplicates. I'll mark it CW and someone who's motivated (or tomorrow when I'm bored I) can go look some up.

Answer (score 1):

Android OutOfMemoryError

- [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue)
- [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949066/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-bitmap-size-exceeds-vm-budget-android)
- [android java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938164/android-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

A simple google search will reveal [all](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+outofmemoryerror+in+android&hl=en&prmd=ivns&ei=-EUsTbSfHs3wrQfT9_mHCg&start=0&sa=N)

Answer (score 1):

Anything where the answer is `dos2unix`. The symptoms are varied and the clue quotient of the OPs is mostly, shall we say, chequered. In the end, by the time it's solved, it's obviously off-topic for SO, but you see some good programming and debugging coaching in the speculations leading up to that.

The examples I am finding are less spectacular than the best I've seen. These all contain literally `dos2unix` in the answer, but there will be hundreds more with different wording.

- [running script file in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973427/running-script-file-in-ubuntu)
- [Looping in Bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555920/looping-in-bash-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-file)
- [Running Executable from Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14825503/running-executable-from-shell-script)
- [Script showing bad interpreter and will not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556524/script-showing-bad-interpreter-and-will-not-run)
- [Bash script always prints "Command Not Found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362504/bash-script-always-prints-command-not-found)
- [ORA-06550 and PLS-00103](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270818/ora-06550-and-pls-00103)
- [Why are ^M and ^[ being appended to my files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670985/why-are-m-and-being-appended-to-my-files)
- [Issue with making python program executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604917/issue-with-making-python-program-executable)

Answer (score 1):

Having voted to close more than 1600 questions, and succeeding in many of them, these are the two I found (anecdotal) most annoying (in number, yes) from C#/.NET world:

1. [Get property name and type using lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273941/get-property-name-and-type-using-lambda-expression)
2. And even more duplicated is this: [Conditional operator assignment with Nullable<value> types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75746/conditional-operator-assignment-with-nullablevalue-types)
3. And even more: [Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class?lq=1)

That's just from my experience. The language designers can take a cue to find the most requested feature..

Answer (score 1):

I'm interested in Java, but every Java regular expression question I see seems to be "plz send me teh regex".

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the one I encounter the most is along the lines of "How come .1 + .1 + .1 doesn't equal .3?".