# Programmer friendly search engine for SO?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [We need to be able to search for punctuation (symbols)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/we-need-to-be-able-to-search-for-punctuation-symbols)

I think it would be really nice if the SO search engine was more programmer friendly.

For instance, [?? operator](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%3F%3F+operator) yields no relevant results and skips the "??" in searching.

I think there should be a way to force symbols to be searched upon. Maybe like a search like `{??} operator` forcing the search engine to include "??" as a phrase to search upon.

Comment: http://www.symbolhound.com is a tool that you can use to search SO (and more and more other programming sites each day) for special characters. A search for "?? operator" on symbolhound produces: http://symbolhound.com/?q=%3F%3F+operator