# Searching for "PHP ===" is worthless on stackoverflow

Tags: feature-request, search, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [We need to be able to search for punctuation (symbols)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/we-need-to-be-able-to-search-for-punctuation-symbols)

There's a recent question asking the difference between PHP's == and ===:

[What's the difference between == and ===?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116656/whats-the-difference-between-and)

A bunch of people downvoted the question and asked if the OP did any googling.  However, googling for "php == vs ===" or "php ===" turns up front page results which are not very helpful.  Even worse, searching for those strings on stackoverflow is not helpful at all.  It seems that the search function completely ignores "==" and "===".  Looking in the "search tips" page (https://stackoverflow.com/search) doesn't mention anything about it.

I think that on a programming site, queries shouldn't ignore common programming operators like == and ===.

Comment: I find this applies to other searches that rely heavily on symbols.  For instance yesterday I was searching for questions on the virtual path symbol in asp.net (~).  Eventually I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353165/converting-virtual-path-to-actual-web-path-in-asp-net but I didn't know it was called "virtual path" and only used the tilde symbol.  This also applied to my search for information on server code blocks using the <% %> symbols : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240424/in-asp-net-embedded-code-blocks .  I have been frustrated by this several times.

Comment: Of course, you have to know about the post in advance for it to do you any good, but for reference: [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3737139)

Comment: @tim see http://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters

Comment: @pseudo see http://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters