# Does the SO search engine require escape characters?

Tags: support, search, special-characters

I'm trying to do a search in the SO search engine for C code questions that contain the `%*s` specificer. The search I'm using is: [c] "%*s", I've also tried it with `s

The problem is that the search engine isn't pulling up any results containing this specificer (and I know there's at least [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000556/what-does-the-s-format-specifier-mean)), I think it's using the `*` as a wildcard instead.

I saw some answers on MSO to similar questions suggesting to use [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/) but it seems I can't apply the "C" tag there, so I'm stuck searching every `%*s` in every language (apparently it comes up in MATLAB a lot).

So is there a way to either "escape" the `*` in the SO search or apply the `[c]` tag using symbolhound... or some other mechanism I'm missing?

Comment: There is a feature-request floating somewhere asking for symbol search support on SO here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/we-need-to-be-able-to-search-for-punctuation-symbols

Comment: [Maybe this?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+code%3A%22%25*s%22)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - That's good... be great if it got put in. In the mean time can we escape characters or am I SOL?

Comment: @TimStone Hey, that's not bad!

Comment: @TimStone - Yeah, that actually turned up what I was looking for, (I knew someone had to have asked that). If you can post your suggestion as a Answer I'd be happy to accept.

Comment: It appears it [was broken in April 2022](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you can use the super-secret, undocumented `code:` operator with quotation marks to get what you're after by [searching for `[c] code:"s*%"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+code%3A%22%25%2As%22).

I'm not sure that search is necessarily interpreting `*` as a wildcard, but you sometimes have to be a bit direct to get it to do what you want (and know about hidden operators).