# How do I escape [*] in search?

Tags: support, search

I am trying to search for .NET questions containing `Type.GetType("System.Double[*]")`. But I can't seem to get the search to work, due to a "tag wildcard" (`[*]`) being interpreted.

Comment: how did you try? Also, [it's not that many results.](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B.net%5D+Type.GetType+System.Double+%5B*%5D) Even when not restricting to [tag:.net] you only have 23 results..

Comment: @Vogel612 you are missing the `[*]`. Sorry I was unclear in my question. That is the important part. If I find a result for `System.Int32[*]` that would be just as good. The question was about escaping that string. PS I went ahead and asked the question on SO and received and answer. But I am leaving this up, since it seems that you can't escape `*`.

Comment: edited. Just now I understood your problem. You want to interpret the brackets as plain text. The error here is not the wildcard then, but the fact that the search does not allow escaping "tag-search"

Comment: You could use the `code:` operator, but it seems to hide the `(` and `)`..

Comment: @3ventic I tried. It seems not to escape the * operator, but works with the square brackets.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/we-need-to-be-able-to-search-for-punctuation-symbols, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153438/does-the-so-search-engine-require-escape-characters