# Search using symbols is broken

Tags: bug, status-review, search, symbols

We used to be able to [use symbols in search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19870/we-need-to-be-able-to-search-for-punctuation-symbols), but that now appears to be broken.

I'd expect a [search for `[python] += list`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%2B%3D+list) to return a result, but instead the search engine appears to put quotes around the whole request; the search box shows the search has been replaced with `"[python] += list"` and the [specific result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347265/why-does-behave-unexpectedly-on-lists) I was looking for doesn't appear among the returned questions.

Using quotes around the symbols do not seem to help here; [`[python] "+=" list`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+%22%2B%3D%22+list) returns an empty result.

Comment: Not meant as a solution but as a temporary work-around use [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/284162) although not useful if you're looking for recent posts or when you have a major tag (python just happens to work...)

Comment: You have only hit the tip of an [iceberg](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279945). This behavior is far more expansive than anyone realizes.

Comment: Note to future self: if this is ever fixed, remember to add instructions back to the help center: [Search for special characters isn't working as advertised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368516/search-for-special-characters-isnt-working-as-advertised)

Comment: Finally the service itself was broken [in April 2022](https://stackapps.com/questions/2690/symbolhound-search-stack-overflow-for-special-characters#comment18724_2690).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum this post is has nothing to do with symbolhound, which was an external service. The StackExchange search *here* used to support symbol searches, at least between 2013 and 2015.