# Why does quoting [ ] characters not search for the [ ] characters in a post title?

Tags: bug, search, title, special-characters

I know there is a question recently about the usefulness of the [filter](/questions/tagged/filter). This is mentioned in the [question title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341527/lets-disambiguate-burninate-filter/341910#341910) as "[Filter]". The full title is:

> Let's disambiguate / burninate [filter]

When I search for `"[Filter]"` it does show up on the most recent questions, since it also mentions `"filter"` in the body of the text.

[image]

If I switch to the most relevant posts, which is the standard setting, I see it as the 10th post, while none of the posts above it make a mention of `"[Filter]"`.

According to what I read in various questions the SE search engine should be able to search for special character when encapsulated in double quotes. These quotes are also not "smart quotes" as I read those don't currently function.

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: SE search is known to not do well on symbol search: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249848/search-using-symbols-is-broken use SEDE ...

Comment: According to this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161785/361484 it should work

Comment: Shog his comment/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368827/578411  is more accurate:somewhere in the Elastic upgrades this got unfixed.

Comment: Okay thx @rene, then I'll remove the discussion tag as it definetly is a bug.