# Something is wrong with the search function when dealing with Devanagari letters

Tags: bug, search, localization, languages, blockquote

I wanted to locate [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/23530/277) of mine and I remember that I have cited a Sanskrit verse "द्वा सुपर्णा...." (see the first quote in the answer) and hence I entered  that string in search bar but it is found that search function is not working as expected with [Devanagari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) script.

**If I just search the string without applying any operator like `user:me` , `is:a` then it is working**; [Try this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE+%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%BE)

You'll find that Devanagari script is broken but still search is working

> [image]

**If I add `is:a` then it doesn't give any result.** [Try it](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa+%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE+%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%BE):

> [image]

Same problem prevails for `user:277` query, [Try that](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A277+%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE+%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%BE)

So, I think something gets wrong with Devanagari script while adding operator to the search function.

**But When I tested it on MSE, I found that using operators `is:q` and `user:me` works fine!!** Try [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE+%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%BE) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A260388+%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE+%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%BE).

> [image]

Why is it working for MSE but not for HSE?

<sub>After editing, it stopped working for MSE also.</sub>

I am investigating this further.

Comment: Note that I have used tag localization and languages but I am not sure if they are appropriate. Consider re-tagging if you find it necessary.

Comment: Just for reference, since I don't think any of the dev team read devanagari - its left to right like english, and letters making words.

Comment: Slightly different problem: none of those search links show any results for me on the app, so I think the API doesn’t handle it correctly either.

Comment: @Laurel Don't try Android app. It never searches in the answers.

Comment: @Pandya it’s the iOS app, which does search in answers. (Still pretty broken in other ways, but its problems are more tolerable than the website.)

Comment: I know that letters used in specific languages are not symbols but do know that SE search always had trouble with finding things that were not in the latin characterset, for example [symbol search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249848/search-using-symbols-is-broken)

Answer (score 2):

Something's wrong with whatever parses the search string, when you add the `is:a` bit. Note the response:

> We couldn't find anything for **दव सपरण**

It has actually split out the combined characters into separate ones.

If I search for [`"द्वा सुपर्णा" is:a`](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A3%E0%A4%BE%22%20is%3Aa), it works correctly.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it works for MSE but not for HSE?

Comment: +1 Quoting the string solves the problem. Still I think we are missing something. See the first screenshot दव सपरण is working if used without any filter.