# How are search results ranked?

Tags: discussion, search, lucene

I couldn't find much on the new Lucene-based search, and don't know much about the engine in general, so I'm asking this question.

Does anybody have a description of how search results are ranked?

Does the rank calculation include:

- rep of post's author?
- views?
- unique referers?
- PageRank of referers?
- rank of questions that link to the post?
- whether a question is closed?
- vote count?
- answer count?

Answer (score 1):

There are several rankings, it depends which tab you're on, there are 4:

- **Relevance** (default): The strength of the search match, only Lucene's internal score matters here
- **Newest**: Most recently created at the top
- **Votes**: Highest voted at the top
- **Active**: Most recent activity at the top

As to each of your questions: *no* to all but "vote count"...which is of course considered on the vote tab.

Comment: Should I change my question from a [discussion] to a [feature-request], then?

Comment: @Gabe - You can, though I can tell you at this point in time it would certainly be status-declined, since those aren't relevant factors...it depends on what you're *after* as to what is relevant, so anything other than raw content would probably be bad here.  Some components of what you're after are already advanced search options, so if you want to restrict on those you can.

Comment: What makes you think that those factors aren't relevant? The whole reason that Google is useful is that they look at factors besides just the content of the page. You can't even make an Internet search engine that just looks at raw content of the page anymore -- it would be entirely useless.

Comment: @Gabe - How exactly would you combine those to get a rank? Sidebar: comparing us to Google isn't very relevant in itself, since internal vs external linking is a *huge* factor in their ranking, and not at all relevant to us (nor do we have that data).  Overall you're talking about a *tremendous* complication of a current approach that fits most cases.

Comment: Can you please update the answer, now that SE use a different search mechanism? Thanks! :)