# Searching for “fasting” on Medical Sciences does not reproduce reliable results

Tags: feature-request, search, stack-exchange

On [Skeptics meta](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4688/39083), I wrote an answer in which I recommended:

> Instead, why not post on Medical Sciences? I was going to say there are [500 posts](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=fasting) containing the term “fasting” but many of the results are variants on the adjective “fast”, which is quite annoying.

And can I add, also bewildering? I knew better than to search for “fast“ because it is a verb and an adjective. I feared I would also get results containing “fasten” but searching for the noun form **fasting**–I thought–would narrow the field and produce reliable positive results. Not so, among the many many false positives were things such as:

1. Is this an indication that my body metabolizes caffeine **fast**er (or slower?)
2. …the chemicals decompose **fast**er before they can cause massive change to their environment.
3. Don't speak **fast** or act in any way that could frighten the victim.
4. in what way is losing weight **fast**er than this unhealthy?
5. Will taking zinc for colds make my colds go away **fast**er?
6. I'm wondering if our bodies adjust to the constant showering by producing oils **fast**er.
7. One 1998 study shown that microwaving food can lead to **fast**er breakdown of vitamin B12
8. Since the body cannot get blood to the highest point (brain) **fast** enough, it cannot
   function.

I found only one result on the first page, showing a total of fifteen posts, that contained the actual term *fasting*.

> Three randomized controlled clinical trials of **fasting** in humans were identified, and the results were published in 5 articles, all of … which evaluated the effects of **fasting** on surrogate outcomes.

What should I have done? If I had also included the terms "diet" and "healthy“ in the search box that would not have improved the results by all that much, and in the post actually containing the term *fasting* only the term “healthy” is used.

Shouldn't the term “fasting“ be easy to find on a Stack Exchange site dedicated to health?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What should I have done?

The "Advanced Search Tips" ([link](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22fasting%22#) at the top of your search page) say you can use double quotes (") before and after your search terms to look for exact matches. [This seems to work](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22fasting%22).

Another thing you may want to do: Sort the results by Relevance instead of Votes, this seems to at least give most of the posts with the exact match for 'fasting' first.

Comment: How silly of me, I've only used quotes for searching a string, a quote, or specific expressions. I did not know that quotes are also used for single words too. Nevertheless, why aren't the results showing "fasting" at the top of the list followed by the other variants?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I just edited in a reason that may have happened: Your search seems to have been ordered by votes, while 'relevance' should give you the closest matches first :) [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84150/369802) has a bit more info on that, though it's 9 years old so I don't know if it's still relevant.

Comment: I automatically chose "votes" because I wanted to see the most upvoted posts. I would not have thought over 350 results would be negative (or appear to be, because "fast" is also a verb)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell yes, I'm pretty sure that hasn't changed in the last 9 years.