# How help to the development community with the most duplicated questions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

How it may works?

1. I think it is important for the development community to understand what issues are raised again and again (of course by tag or similar tags). This may point on some poor documentation, missing tutorials, etc. Especially if we able to correlate these questions with the user's reputation. I assume here (may be wrongly) that the low reputation mostly belongs to the beginners.
2. Other aspect is hot topics. I guess Stack Overflow will show many duplicated questions about some bug/issue/problem in the new release software. Then the software community may receive fast indication about such issues.

The rational of this question not belongs to the merge issue like in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9686/what-is-the-most-rampant-duplicate-on-stack-exchange-sites) (suggested as the duplicated). I am talking about providing more information to the different development communities that may lead to the site impact increasing.

Comment: (Step 1) Find someone good at SQL, (Step 2) go to [Data Explorer.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/), (Step 3) ??? (Step 4) Profit.

Comment: If your intent on this question is a way for duplicates to be sent to third-party sources so they can fix their documentation or fix bugs, that's barely in the language of what's written in the question

Comment: I changed the title I hope now this is clearly. Thanks!