# Accepted Answer without accepted Mark!

Tags: bug, status-completed, accepted-answer

There is no accepted mark for this answser

> [This question has a reason to be asked: Why isn't this question a duplicate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88789/this-question-has-a-reason-to-be-asked-why-isnt-this-question-a-duplicate)

But see my reputation page, my answer got accepted already.

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/139541/you?tab=reputation#reppage_1-repview_time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahhh I know exactly what happened here, this was a separate bug we had that only affected meta.SO and only affected a handful of votes. (this was not mine for a change)

I just fixed the record in the DB you may want to run yourself a recalc to get your missing rep, if it matters to you :)

Comment: Thanks for the fix, now looks ok :-)

Comment: @waffles: can anyone do a recalc for himself?

Comment: @alex: http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation see the button at the bottom

Comment: @CodyGray and @YOU wow, thanks! I had no idea this got implemented. How long does it take for the reputation to be recalculated?

Comment: @alex, less than a second for me

Comment: @YOU: I thought it would just trigger the rep recalc and it would be done in a couple of hours. Tried it myself here and it was really fast (about a second). Nice to see this got implemented.

Comment: @alex The results are usually not so nice

Comment: @Wether: I got +6 on SO, +2 on meta and 0 on Super User so, all in all, pretty ok.

Comment: @alex I tried it a few times and always lose points. Perhaps it is just designed against _me_ :)