# Similar question = Same User?Duplicate:Different; //Is this true?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, similarity

If two **questions are similar** but have different focal points / purposes, is the newest one a duplicate?

For **example** take my [Japanese captcha question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042408/php-japanese-captcha) (hencefort [QB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042408/php-japanese-captcha)). Deemed a duplicate of my [Chinese captcha question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042022/php-chinese-captcha) (hencefort [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042022/php-chinese-captcha)).

Does this coincide with *SOs definition* of a duplicate question? Let's have a look:

> "This question covers exactly the same ground as earlier questions on this topic;"

True to a degree (if you *ignore* language).

> "its answers may be merged with another identical question."

**False**.

---

[QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042022/php-chinese-captcha) is asking for the name of a **Chinese** captcha whereas [QB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042408/php-japanese-captcha) is looking for a **Japanese** captcha. Look at the accepted answer for [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042022/php-chinese-captcha); it **could not possibly be the answer for [QB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042408/php-japanese-captcha)**.

Furthermore, let's look at the accepted answer from ["When is a duplicate not a duplicate?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/when-is-a-duplicate-question-not-a-duplicate):

> Rule of thumb: If you ask a question similar to another question and it is likely to get the exact same answer, you have yourself a duplicate question.
>
> In your case, take the opposite of that. If the question is similar and it is likely to NOT get the exact same answer, you likely do not have a duplicate.

I know this rule of thumb does not come from SO/SE itself but it seems to me that it has been employed thoroughly on SE **until now**.
Have I managed to find a loophole/exception? Which is; it is *also* a duplicate, if the two (similar) questions were asked by the **same user**.

Can someone clarify if is this true? **Is this now an exception?**

Comment: Your question is extremely confusing, especially the bold text that is unclear as to the reason it is bold.

Comment: Human judgement is fallible, unfortunately.  Reopened.  Also, in future, a flag with details (and links) is usually enough to fix this kind of thing.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "loophole". Decisions are made by people based on their best judgement with a series of guidelines, not a strict set of unmodifiable rules. They may be right or wrong, and you may agree or not.

For your specific case, you can flag the question for mod attention and explain why they are different (in ten words, not several paragraphs), and you can ask also for reopening.

To avoid this issues in the future, make sure you reference your previous (very similar) question and explain in the question itself why this is a new question and why the answers there cannot be used to answer the new question.

Comment: +1 for "reference previous questions and explain ... why this is new ... and **why the answers there cannot be used**" This is part of doing your homework and asking a good question, IMO.

Comment: Once I spotted that someone hinted at a duplicate, I edited the question to include the explanation which is there now but it still eventually was closed. But I will do this from now on if my question is similar to another.

Comment: @Adam yes, I saw the edit, but I have no idea about the timings there. It's always safer to put it from the beginning.