# Bringing chat-like question linking (onebox) to questions and answers

Tags: feature-request, onebox

You know when you insert a pasted link into a chat there is  a nice info tile. Why isn't there something like that in the actual sites? I think it would be great for when you think there is a relevant answer and question, when you think the question is a duplicate.

Comment: You might be interested in [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73991/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/74266#74266)

Answer (score -1):

Chat doesn't allow formatting when you use multi line. It would require a significant amount of effort to reproduce this in chat. However, there are a lot more options when making a real post. You can use editing all over and there are many more options for markdown.

In this post, you can make the same piece manually with little effort.

> **`1288`**  **[Q: FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/178816)**
>   Community FAQ For sites in the Stack Exchange 2.0 network To see a list of
>   commonly used words and phrases, see the glossary. For official guidance
>   from Stack Exchange, visit the Help Center. Asking questions How do I write a good
>   title? How can I get answers fast? Where can I ask a ques...
>   [support](/questions/tagged/support)[faq](/questions/tagged/faq)

versus the chat one-box

[image]

So it wouldn't really make much of a difference. Also, most of the time, just the title will suffice: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/178816)

Chances are, if you are going to need to show an entire one-box of another question in yours, it is potentially a duplicate. And if it is closely related, then showing just the first few lines probably wont capture the context properly.

Also, this would be terrible for comments as they extend far enough. If someone placed 4 links in a comment for related or possible duplicate questions it would be too much noise on the page.