# Flagging homework questions for adding a warning banner at the top

Tags: feature-request

I have been wondering what is the theory behind not moderating out homework questions immediately.

By homework questions I mean questions that do not show almost any kind of effort from the asker to solve it, the asker has very little reputation (or did not even give a name to his account, etc), the pure goal is to get someone else do the job.

I consider this extremely damaging.

First of all, this creates an asymmetry when someone who is knowledgeable devotes time and effort to help, whereas the other party just want free food.

Second of all, *solving* someone problems just confirm his behaviour that instead of him *learning* to do, he succeeds by nagging for someone else's help. Now, that is called **bad teaching**.

Basically the asker learns **nothing** but the fact that there are always suckers who will do the work for him.

Would you like to work with such a guy? Because part of the continuous daily effort all good programmers do is developing themselves, studying constantly, especially new technologies where there is no one to be asked questions.

Now, I read Q&A related to this topic. However, I feel the need for a new moderator action which does not close the question but clearly flags it deprecated to be answered.

People will keep answering all these in good faith because who the hell reads the entire eqiquette and site policy? Also, they are not aware of the damage they cause for the student.

So let's flag the question with a warning about this (showing probably a banner before the question)- does not hurt I guess, but makes people more aware of what is the price of their good intentions.

Please understand: I am not against helping students. I have many students around be and always am happy to help - but there should be an approach to help them to **learn from** not to **abuse** our help.

Comment: Homework questions can show effort like any other question.

Comment: Your definition of "homework" has no correlation to whether or not the problem is actually homework, using the typical definition.  This is highly confusing.  If you don't mean homework, don't call it homework.

Comment: @Servy: I mean homework, and I call it homework. Sorry, what are you trying to say? Don't get it.

Comment: The point is that bad questions should be moderated regardless whether or not they are homework, and good questions should get to live regardless whether or not they are homework.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should Stack Overflow be awarding "A"s for Effort?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort)

Comment: @TFuto You don't mean homework, but you're calling it homework.  You mean questions asking for code, not showing effort, not willing to understand a solution, etc.  Sometimes the person asking such a question is actually doing a homework assignment, sometimes they're not.  Sometimes people asking a question related to a homework problem they have demonstrates effort, an understanding of the problem, research, is clearly asked, etc.  Thus your definition of "homework" has no correlation to whether the question is actually a homework question.

Comment: I am offering/requesting a **feature**: warning banner. I did not want to discuss what his homework question or not, but good discussion nevertheless...

Comment: @TFuto And using improper terms within that discussion leads to people not understanding your proposal, which is why I am informing you of this problem so that you can correct it, rather than see a proposal rejected/criticized simply because people mis-understood you.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding how you're planning to flag these, and who the banner would be showed to.

Comment: @Servy: Well, I actually meant homework-type asking for code, not willing to understand, etc. But you are right, we can generalize that. I did not define myself "homework" differently than what it means, you try to use the word to embrace a more generic area. YOu are actually right, we have this problem in a broader area, but I meant just homework.

Comment: @hichris123: Well, a person could click the "Flag" next to the question, and in the options there would be an additional bullet to flag the question with a "Warning". The question stays open, but the banner is displayed atop of it, if the moderators accept it.

Comment: @TFuto So the banner would be showed to everyone? Most questions like these are going to be closed or deleted, keep that in mind.

Comment: @TFuto: Why would the question need to stay open? What would that achieve? Are the downvotes not enough of a warning? The post can always still be edited and reopened.

Comment: @hichris123: Yes, so that answerers understand the context and instead of giving solutions, they provide coaching to solve it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, if someone wants to help, knowing the circumstances, why not? I am not against HELPING. Also: a warning-flagged question of this type might get different consideration for downvoting by others.

Comment: @TFuto that's a noble motivation, but the signals of a failing question are arguably already there: you see the question's quality, comments others have made, its closevotes, etc... those who want to help the OP can already post comments, and those who want to answer won't be kept from doing so by a banner.

Comment: Leaving the question open shows goodwill from StackExchange. Tagging it with a Warning banner shows care for the answerers, and also let them know what are they actually doing.

Comment: @Pëkka: I do not know, I would challenge that, but you might be right.

Comment: Stack Overflow gets 7,000+ new questions every day. Leaving stuff open is not an option. I agree however that the askers of "failing" questions should get information earlier, not only after closing.

Comment: @Pëkka: This flagging with a Warning is both a good gimmick to warn the asker early and for answerers give a feedback that is not terminal at that moment.

Comment: @TFuto Which is exactly what closing does.

Comment: Maybe an auto-comment on a close vote. @Pëkka

Comment: @Servy: Well, I may be wrong, but isn't it that if it is closed, no one can answer it?

Comment: @hichris yeah ----

Comment: Another option could be to mark with a warning, saying that this question does not meet the base rules, but will be migrated to a StackExchange programming homework-related site?

Comment: @TFuto That is correct, which is a highly effective way of warning would-be answers that this is a question that shouldn't be answered.  It does a lot better job of preventing low quality answers than just applying a banner.

Comment: Okay, I may be wrong then.

Comment: @TFuto Again, you're not talking about actual homework, you're just talking about low quality questions.  We don't want to have a "low quality question" site that we migrated all of our bad questions to.  (Interestingly enough, we had one several years back.  Unsurprisingly, it didn't turn out well.  They're not going to make the same mistake twice.)

Comment: This is a feature-request for a specific feature, so shouldn't be marked as a dupe of a discussion question.

Comment: If the user setting a name or their rep is coming into the equation at all then something has gone very wrong

Comment: @RichardTingle: not necessarily. A user with a lower rep will take more effort to post a question to be answered. This is just to filter out those who have user***** accounts with 2-3 rep asking a question. Their question may be legitimate, but also they could just abuse the system. A few rep does not hurt, shows the goodwill of the user, also adds value to StackExchange, and also shows that the person is here to learn not to rip off others' time.

Comment: @TFuto And how exactly are they to get this rep if all their questions are automatically defined as bad. Judge the question, never the user. If I, as a 10k user post a poor quality, lazy question it should be treated exactly the same as a user that registered 10 minutes ago

Comment: @RichardTingle: Why would their question be *automatically* be defined as bad? I did not propose that. And you do not get my point. You are right about the 10k user post! That is question quality issue. My issue is to WARN answerers to instead of helping full blast, use a COACH/TRAINER approach. I am not asking to mark questions BAD. Where did you read that? Probably in the other comments, not me!! :-))

Comment: This ", the asker has very little reputation (or did not even give a name to his account, etc)" is the bit I am questioning

Comment: @RichardTingle: Well, if someone starts to learn new things, he can be in the same shoe: asking seemingly clever but actually stupid questions. However, I would differentiate between a person who has no rep and one who has tons of rep. High rep + clever question: will have upvotes, great. High rep + stupid question: will have downvotes, but people seeing the rep may be more tolerant. Low rep + clever questions: will make the asker very quickly high rep, so no problem. Low rep + stupid question: you cannot decide whether the guy is brilliant or wasting our time.

Comment: @RichardTingle: there are many people here who can just look at a question and see whether that is a genuine problem or the asker just did not care. Let them FLAG the question if the user is low rep! If he is high rep, downvote or whatever. But it may be that the low rep guy needs help, so instead of killing the question, it should be deprecated for answers, but left open for awhile more, for supporting the guy if someone wants to. Consider it a warning + a delayed automatic close.

Comment: Actually my experience of low quality questions from high rep users is they are more harshly recieved along with "you should know better than this" comments

Comment: @RichardTingle: You are right :-). Still, a high rep guy will take this less seriously than a beginner user of the site. The are not going to think bad of the site, just send the critics to hell! But a newbie may just skip using this site at all. My intention is: to keep the good guys IN and the lazy ones OUT.

Comment: It looks to me like the concerns you have are about what we call ["help vampires"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119858/how-can-we-stop-help-vampires) on Meta, rather than "homework questions".

Comment: When I was in college many years ago (1979-1984) I had a part time job being a "consultant" to the other students to help them with their programming problems. This was approved by the school who had a room set aside just for this purpose. We would never write the code solution for them. Instead we would review their problem, and point them in the right direction, by either asking them a pertinent question or point them at the section of code that had the issue. At worst I would get to pointing them at the line of code with the bug. It was better suited to get them to think.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a question doesn't demonstrate any research effort, attempts at a solution, is clearly just asking for a fully coded solution to a problem, and you feel they don't even have a basic understanding of the underlying concepts they are asking about, there *is* a close reason just for this, as a sub-reason for "off topic":

> Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: However, there is a difference between showing effort and showing minimum understanding. The difference is a person *being able* to understand an answer (off-topic if they can't) vs. not showing effort (not off-topic per se).