# Do 20% of the top voted questions really provide 80% of the answers for beginners in a tag?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, new-users

This assumption is of course joking, but say you start to learn jQuery. At the beginning, the questions you will have will be similar to those of most beginners. So in all likelihood, these questions have already been asked by someone earlier on, and they were voted on by the people who were also faced with those problems at the beginning of their study.

Is it really the case that 20% of the top voted questions will provide you with 80% of the answers to the most frequent problems? Does the Pareto principle work here?

Comment: Sure, the Pareto rule may or may not apply to Stack Overflow questions and answers. However, what are you discussing here, exactly?

Comment: I'll vote to reopen this because it's no longer "unclear". Whether or not it's a good answerable question though, I don't really know.

Comment: Yes probably. In the tags I follow I see a very small proportion of questions that ask something genuinely new that hasn't already been covered elsewhere on the site. Often the questions are just quite localised about how to apply this to their situation.

Comment: @Bart fair enough. Following your lead. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Famous last words.

Comment: I'm not sure if discussion questions really have to be good answerable questions.

Comment: There are 353,095 jQuery questions at the moment. It would be pretty miraculous if the top ~70,000 questions didn't cover a lot of basic issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be talking about the "tall head" of popular questions, as opposed to the "long tail" of less-popular niche questions. Certainly the Pareto principle applies to questions in most disciplines, and this idea has been present in the development of SO from the every beginning.

Jeff Atwood's blog post "[The Wikipedia of Long Tail Programming Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)" (see also: a [related Meta response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73991/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions)) addresses a lot of your ideas:

> Have you ever noticed how certain questions come up again and again on Stack Overflow sites?
>
> Oh look, my PC is freezing. Should I use `SELECT *`? Oh, and, how can I host a server from home?
>
> Really, people, do you want to be answering these same questions ten years from now? How about when you’re 65? That doesn't sound so appealing now, does it?

The post is a good overview of why Stack Overflow was built with support for marking duplicates. There are a few questions that everyone has, and then a large volume of questions that very few people have.

[image: long tail diagram]

Atwood goes on to say:

> **Help us build a great library of canonical answers.** If you keep seeing the same form of questions, whether it’s mod_rewrite rules on Server Fault, freezing computers on Super User, or how to use regular expressions to parse HTML, write a great, canonical answer, once and for all.

Answers on Stack Exchange sites are intended to be useful to *many* people in the future, not only the original asker. Duplicates help ensure that even though a thousand people have the same question, we don't need to have a thousand individual copies of the question on the site.

Comment: That might be the original idea but the gamification incentives act against it. As discussed elsewhere on meta (e.g. [Reward finding duplicate questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5) )there is no incentive to search for a dupe if you can just post a quick answer and get rep.